# Cannot use replace method inside a function

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery ( function ( $ ) {   

var textarea = $('.project');
var $counter = $('.chars');

var limit = 200;
var initial = 0;

$(textarea).on('keypress keyup copy paste', function(){
    displayLength();
});


function displayLength() {
     var thisChars = textarea.val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').length; 
    if (thisChars > limit) {
        $counter.text(thisChars + ' of 200 chars');
        var CharsToDel = (thisChars-totalChars); 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,textarea.value.length-CharsToDel);

    } else {
        $counter.text(initial + thisChars + ' of 200 chars');

    }
}

displayLength();

});
```

The scenario is when I am on the create page, it would show 0 of 200 chars. Then when typing in textbox, it would display increasing chars. Also it won't count new line or spaces. So when save the created page, it will still display number of chars on new page, i.e. edit. The problem is that the console shows error 'cannot call method 'replace' of undefined.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: use `textarea.val()` instead of `textarea.value`

Comment: @BrianGlaz IYTM `.val()`

Comment: @crush s/good/valid/ ..

Comment: @Alnitak yup, that's what I meant.. haha. updated comment.

Comment: @BrianGlaz - thanks. and now problem is that it is not calculating correctly. for example copying text of 200 chars returns 201 chars. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('anything that is not on the page').val()` is `undefined`, which does not have the `replace` method. To briefly circumvent this error for before the DOM is done loading your `.project` textarea, consider using `$(document).ready`, or swapping `undefined` with `''` for that special case:

```
var thisChars = (textarea.val() || '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').length;  // laziest solution
```

A more proper solution should check if textarea is available to the function:

```
function displayLength() {
    if (textarea.val() === undefined) {
        return;  // do not run any further.
    }
    var thisChars = textarea.val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').length; 
    if (thisChars > limit) {
        $counter.text(thisChars + ' of 200 chars');
        var CharsToDel = (thisChars-totalChars); 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,textarea.value.length-CharsToDel);

    } else {
        $counter.text(initial + thisChars + ' of 200 chars');

    }
}
```

Comment: The OP _has_ a `$(document).ready()` function - that's what `jQuery(function($) {...})` does too.  This answer appears to be a case of fixing the symptoms and not curing the real problem (which I must admit appears unclear).

Answer (score 0):

Why use JS at all to limit the length when it is built into the HTML spec?

```
<textarea class="project" maxlength="200"></textarea>
```

If you choose to keep the JS limiting functionality, you will need to change it to something along the following lines:

```
$(textarea).on('keypress keyup copy paste', function(e){
    displayLength(e);
});


function displayLength(e) {
     var thisChars = textarea.val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').length;

     if (thisChars === limit)
         e.preventDefault();
}
```

Not sure how well `e.preventDefault` works with copy/paste events.

Comment: oh. html spec. it looks simple enough. ill try this and see.